# GUI for Editing XML?

Tags: java, html, xml, jsp

i need to create GUI for editing xml document showing the XML in tree view and displaying the need node name and value in a text box for editing. Please let me know if any tool/framework available for this.

Note: its a web application using jsp

Comment: There is a related question on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378205/web-xml-editor-with-xml-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 1):

You could use eclipse. Download "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look on [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/platform/) or [Netbeans platform](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/) as a start.

These are for desktop applications. Not sure if you are looking for webApp or desktop app since you didn't mention it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't any specific toolkit that could build a GUI for you but [xml spy](http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/) could give you ideas on how you want your GUI to look like:

[image]